# Optimize query used to calculate invoice last month

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I use the following query in order to calculate the invoice last month. how could I simplify it ?

```
SELECT     
    T1.SNAP, SUM(T3.INVC) AS INV2
FROM
    stg.sales AS T1 
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT     
         CONVERT(NVARCHAR(6), PERI) AS PERI, 
         YEAR(SNAP) AS ANNE, 
         MONTH(SNAP) AS MOIS
     FROM          
         stg.sales
     WHERE      
         (DAY(SNAP) = 1)
     UNION
     SELECT     
         CONVERT(NVARCHAR(6), DATEADD(MONTH, - 2, MIN(SNAPDATE)), 112) AS PERI, 
         MIN(YEAR) AS ANNE, 
         MIN(MONTH) AS MOIS
     FROM         
         dbo.SALES_Daily) AS T2 ON T2.ANNE = T1.ANNEE AND T2.MOIS = T1.MOIS  
INNER JOIN
    csk.Data_Invc AS T3 ON CONVERT(NVARCHAR(6), T3.SNAP, 112) = T2.PERI
GROUP BY 
    T1.SNAP
```

Comment: Start by using good table aliases, vs. T1, T2 etc. Makes it un-necessarily hard to follow the query.

Comment: Yeah the formatting and aliases make it more difficult to decipher but what do you mean by simplify? Are you really trying to improve performance? Not sure what the real objective is here.

Comment: Hello and Welcome to StackOverflow! I believe you should read [what topics can I ask in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Also, I suggest posting that to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: try making your Converts on peri and snap into calculated fields and try adding indexes.

Comment: so that is to say, make computed field versions of CONVERT(NVARCHAR(6), T3.SNAP, 112) and CONVERT(NVARCHAR(6), PERI), then experiment with persisting them and with indexes - to see if you can get a big speed up, plus other indexes as appropriate.  Also you need to look at the queryExecution plan

Comment: If its a large data set I would think all those aggregates functions in the sub query cost you a lot after time. Also, instead o trying to join on the sub query with all of the aggs in it, I would consider a non recursive CTE (common table expression) and then join form there. Im thinking the aggregates in the join its self is causing nested loops which in turn eats at your performance. Filling an inline table with the data precalc'd before the join will prolly be a huge impact. This is just a guess though so I could be way off base.

Comment: And you have a convert in the join statement as well. Double hit on performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested but I think this might give you a real boost. If I am way off base, then i apologize. Without sample data to play with Im kind of shooting in the dark here.

```
; WITH cte AS 
    (
        SELECT     
             CONVERT(NVARCHAR(6), PERI) AS PERI, 
             YEAR(SNAP) AS ANNE, 
             MONTH(SNAP) AS MOIS
         FROM          
             stg.sales
         WHERE      
             (DAY(SNAP) = 1)
         UNION
         SELECT     
             CONVERT(NVARCHAR(6), DATEADD(MONTH, - 2, MIN(SNAPDATE)), 112) AS PERI, 
             MIN(YEAR) AS ANNE, 
             MIN(MONTH) AS MOIS
         FROM         
             dbo.SALES_Daily
    )
, Anothercte AS 
    (
        SELECT
            CONVERT(NVARCHAR(6), SNAP, 112) As ConvSNAP
            , INVC
        FROM 
            csk.Data_Invc
    )
SELECT 
    s.SNAP, SUM(di.INVC) AS INV2
FROM
    stg.sales AS s
INNER JOIN
    cte ON cte.ANNE = s.ANNEE AND cte.MOIS = s.MOIS  
INNER JOIN
    Anothercte AS di ON di.ConvSNAP = cte.PERI
GROUP BY 
    s.SNAP
```